# $. function signature in jquery

Tags: jquery

In jquery, what does the following notation mean

$.function

Is it to show a function is globally available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$` is an alias to the `jQuery` object, so `$.function` is the same as calling `jQuery.function`.

Edit: It also applies to the [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Answer (score 1):

This function behaves just like $(document).ready(), in that it should be used to wrap other $() operations on your page that depend on the DOM being ready. While this function is, technically, chainable, there really isn't much use for chaining against it.

$ is basically a way to call the jQuery class.

Comment: That's my understanding too - $.function() == $(document).ready().function()

Answer (score 0):

No, in jQuery, the jQuery object, is aliased as $ as well, so instead of writing:

```
jQuery.doSomething();
```

you can write

```
$.doSomething();
```